# Launch pygames from a pygame menu

Tags: python, pygame

Good day, Stack Overflow

I've been working on a project that is a bunch of different minigames, and I have the menu and games all written up, the problem is, how would I go about writing code to launch these games if the right button is pressed, and then make the menu re-launch when the game is finished?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually very simple. Your main loop should have sub loops. Each sub loop is a single game. If you hit button one you run loop 1. If you hit button 2 you run loop 2 etc. something like this..

```
while mainloop:

    select=True
    button1 = False
    button2 = False

    while select:

        if button1 == True:
            button1 = False
            select = False
            game1 = True

        elif button2 == True:
            button2 = False
            select = False
            game2 = 2

    while game1:
        # the game loop

        if player_die is True:
            game1 = False
            select = True

    while game2:
        # the game loop

        if player_die is True:
            game2 = False
            select = True
```

something like the above should work. You work out the rest. Remember!! Try before asking..